# Why custom fonts on my websites does not work

Tags: css

It works before I add support for .ttf, .eot and .svg, but now, it doesn't work anymore.

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
    font-family: 'qianxsnjgregular';
    src: url('./font/zh/qxsn-webfont.eot');
    src: url('./font/zh/qxsn-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./font/zh/qxsn-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./font/zh/qxsn-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./font/zh/qxsn-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
body {
    font-family: 'qianxsnjgregular', SimHei, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it work on any browsers?

Comment: Please explain further what have you tried, what did you change exactly to the CSS etc.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work on any browsers. I only changed styles.css and css for my fonts That was my css for font before: `  @charset "UTF-8";
 @font-face {
     font-family: 'qianxsnjgregular';
    src: url('./font/zh/qxsn-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('./font/zh/qxsn-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     font-display: swap;
 }
   body {
  font-family: 'qianxsnjgregular', SimHei, sans-serif;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
 }`

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded all the font files, and I found that only the WOFF and WOFF2 files are working. The others are broken. The browser take a font that cannot be read.

Comment: then what should i do to fix it

Comment: Convert the WOFF into other file types and add them to your website.

Comment: Alright I’ll try it, thanks!

Comment: Also, WOFF format is well supported by all browsers (except Opera Mini), as it was made for the web. Check [this link](https://caniuse.com/woff).